# How to use for loop to make subset dataframes

Tags: r

I have a dataset composed of columns including: Indicator, Value, Province, goal number, and ranking. Based on this dataset, I would like to make provincial datasets. In other words, I would like to make subsets of the dataset  titled by the name of province. How can I do it this with for loop? Or is there any other way?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `split` function.

Comment: Try `split(df,factor = df$Province)` where `df` is your `data.frame`. People will be able to help you in a much better way if you could share a sample of your data  in the question description. You can share output of `dput(head(df))` in the question description.

Answer (score 1):

Cosidering your data frame name as 'df' and the column on which you want to split into small data frames as 'Province' use below code

```
library(plyr)
list_df = dlply(df, "Province", identity)
list2env(list_df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.

Assume you have a `data.frame` like this:

```
ex <-  data.frame("Indicator" = c(1,1,2,1), "Value" = c(2,3,4,1), 
"Province" = c("a","a","b","b"), "goal number" = c(1,1,1,1),
"ranking" = c(1,1,5,5))

ex
 Indicator Value Province goal.number ranking
1         1     2        a           1       1
2         1     3        a           1       1
3         2     4        b           1       5
4         1     1        b           1       5
```

then you can use `subset` to make subsets of your `data.frame`:

```
 subset(ex, ex$Province == "a")

   Indicator Value Province goal.number ranking
 1         1     2        a           1       1
 2         1     3        a           1       1
```

For future questions: Please provide an [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).